# Ending a function if it's taking more than 1 second to finish

Tags: python, sockets, exception, signals

I'm not experienced at all with Python, but I'm trying to use it to resolve some hostnames from IP addresses. I can do this with socket.gethosybyaddr. By default, you can't set a custom timeout on this function, which is unfortunate because if I can't resolve a hostname in less than 1 second, I'm not interested in the answer.

I looked at this post to try to implement one by myself, but it's not been working out:

```
import socket,signal

ips = ['190.213.192.39','92.247.222.20','85.65.191.56','174.36.30.111','209.17.73.30','64.4.35.57','65.54.95.149']

def handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception('timeout')

def resolve(ip):
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
    except: 
        pass


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
for ip in ips:
    signal.alarm(1)
    print resolve(ip)
```

I do actually get a Exception: timeout when I can't resolve an IP, but it takes way more than 1 second to get there. Also I'm not sure I'm actually implementing the idea the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: You may want to have a look at an asynchronous resolver library adns, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adns

Comment: The main problem in the code above seens to be you are not cancelling the alrm with a call  ` signal.alarm(0)` after calling resolve.  

Also, you should not use a "blank" exception - and much less with a `pass` statement: you may be getting **any** error there, and it is being silenced by the `except: pass` statement.
Inherit a (blank) class from Exception, raise it on timeout, and catch only this custom exception on your `except` clause.